# Realtime shared folder on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, real-time

I'm working on an intranet for a school, I would like to set up online folders for students, some kind of Google Drive-ish folder, one for each class.

So far, I managed to create it, but I would like to add some improvements.
Basically, each Class has many Resources, and each Resource has an attached file (with Paperclip). So, for now, I'm using Dropzone, and each time a student uplaods a file, it works just fine, but other student have to refresh to see the file.

I was wondering if there was a way to upload resources in real-time, so that everytime a student uploads a file, all other students can see it appear as soon as it is uploaded.

I searched for a bit, on one hand, I have the Publish/Subscribe which appears to bring some kind of realtime, but only for messengers-like applications, and on the other hand, I got some gems, like Remotipart, which allow to upload files asynchronously.

Is there a way to combine both ?

I'm using RoR 4

Answer (score 0):

By using **Remotipart**, only the student who uploads the document can see the uploaded data & no other students can see it.
 You can do a patch by polling.
Hit a Ajax request after few seconds which will fetch the data from the server & append it on the HTML